# Using events and BackgroundWorker to update UI causing race conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have two classes, `Apple` and `Dog`.  Both of these classes have a method called upon startup, `DoLotsOfWork()` which publish an event `ProgressChanged`.

```
public class Apple
{
    //For progress bars
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
    private void OnProgressChanged(double progress)
    {
        if(ProgressChanged != null)
            ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs((int)(progress * 100), null));
    }

    //Takes a long time to run
    public void DoLotsOfWork()
    {
        for(lots of things)
        {
            ...
            OnProgressChanged(percentage);
        }
    }
}
//Dog is similar
```

To keep the UI from locking up, I have these run using a `BackgroundWorker`.  I have `Apple.ProgressChanged` and `Dog.ProgressChanged` call `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` *(which calls the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event)* to update a label and a progress bar, so the user knows what's going on.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private Apple _apple;
    private Dog _dog;
    private bool _isAppleCompleted;

    ...

    //Set the ProgressChanged callbacks and start the BackgroundWorker
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _apple.ProgressChanged += (a, args) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(args.ProgressPercentage);
        _dog.ProgressChanged += (a, args) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(args.ProgressPercentage);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    //Invoke the UI thread to set the status/progress
    private void SetStatus(string status)
    {
        lblStatus.Invoke((Action)(() => lblStatus.Text = status));
    }
    private void SetProgress(int progress)
    {
        progressBar.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar.Value = progress));
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _isAppleCompleted = false;
        SetStatus("Apple (Step 1/2)");
        _apple.DoLotsOfWork();

        //Thread.Sleep(1); //This *sometimes* fixes the problem!?

        _isAppleCompleted = true;
        SetStatus("Dog (Step 2/2)");
        _dog.DoLotsOfWork();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //_apple.DoLotsOfWork should cause the progress bar to go from 0 to 50
        //_dog.DoLotsOfWork should cause the progress bar to go from 50 to 100
        int progress = (_isAppleCompleted ? 50 : 0) + e.ProgressPercentage/2;
        SetProgress(progress);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

**What I expect to happen:** The text *"Apple (Step 1/2)"* as the progress bar moves from 0% to 50%.  Then the phrase "Dog (Step 2/2)" is displayed as the progress bar moves from 50% to 100%.

**What actually happens:** Only the text "Dog (Step 2/2)" is ever displayed.  The progress bar goes from 0% to 100%, then goes back to 50% and moves up to 100%.

---

Since I *thought* events handlers are run on the same thread as the event-caller; and I *thought* `Control.Invoke()` blocks until the `Action` is completed, I don't see how there could be any race conditions, since everything is essentially happening synchronously.  **Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening, and how to fix it?**

And yes, I checked that `0 <= e.ProgressPercentage <= 100`, and `progressBar.Maximum = 100`.

Comment: Your assumptions at the bottom are correct, though you should note that the BackgroundWorker is going to raise ProgressChanged on the thread that the control was created on, so calling backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress from the worker thread invokes the ProgressChanged handler on the UI thread (assuming that's where you created the backgroundworker), so not everything is happening synchronously. It also means the Invoke in your private SetProgress method is unnecessary.

Comment: Does DoLotsOfWork on _apple actually take a long time?  If not, you wont notice a different in the status text.  Doing Thread.Sleep(1000) should make the transition more obvious (where you currently have the sleep commented out).

Comment: @roken: *["The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns immediately."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx)* - I see.  That could be my issue.  Then I would need to edit the `_apple/_dog.ProgressChanged` handlers to loop on some volatile boolean to wait until `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` has completed *(or use a Semaphore)*?  Or is there a better, non-blocking way?

Comment: @roken: Yep that was my issue - if you create an answer I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions at the bottom are correct, though you should note that the BackgroundWorker is going to raise ProgressChanged on the thread that the control was created on, so calling backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress from the worker thread invokes the ProgressChanged handler on the UI thread (assuming that's where you created the backgroundworker), so not everything is happening synchronously. It also means the Invoke in your private SetProgress method is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the Invoke() method in your background worker, you're defeating the purpose of having the background worker.  To update your progress:
1. the BackgroundWorker should call the ReportProgress method.
2. in the BackgroundWorker control on the WinForm, add a ProgressChanged handler to update your progress

Comment: I don't see how using `Invoke()` *"defeats the purpose of having the background worker."*  And your suggestion is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's as I said in my comments on the question, the BackgroundWorker is designed to raise its events on the UI thread so that you don't have to invoke the call yourself.

Comment: The background worker should raise events which get handled in the UI, not manipulate UI elements directly